# How to set DetailViewController to support all orientation?

Tags: objective-c

This is my view hierarchy:

TabBarController => NavigationController => FistTableViewController => SecondTableViewController => DetailViewController

I've set my TabBarController to support only portrait mode and that's also apply to all other ViewController underneath it.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);}
```

But the thing is, I want my DetailViewController which is the last ViewController to support all orientation with the code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);}
```

But it's not work! It's stay still in portrait mode.
Any other solution?

Comment: just `return YES;` in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`

Comment: which controller should I set it?

Comment: the view controller you want to rotate. If you want to rotate a tab bar application, you need to enable rotation in all it's child view controllers.

Comment: I've set it to both TabBarController and DetailViewController but still not working! :(

Comment: maybe you are using other controllers and you don't know. check for that. Also check your Info.plist file to see if you have all your orientations supported. And in worst case, add a notification for rotation using the `NSNotification` system. This last solution is not the most elegant one, but it will work 100%.

Comment: So how to add NSNotification system?

Answer (score 0):

For Autorotation to work with UITabBarController and UINavigationController, there are some conditions:

1. Incase of UITabBarController, autorotation only works if all the controllers in the tab bar support it.
2. Incase of UINavigationController, autorotation only works if the rootViewController in the navigation controller supports it.